# converting an ARGB 8888 image into yuv 420 sp in android causing greenish imag

Tags: image-processing

Hello I am trying to convert an ARGB 8888 image into yuv 420 sp in android and I am getting a totally greenish and compressed image.Please help me in code if I am doing it the correct way.
The code seems something as below.

```
            Image(Context context) {
                // This Constructor is used to initialize height and width of screen
                screenHeight = 800;//m1.heightPixels;
                screenWidth = 480;//m1.widthPixels;
                bufferSize = 4 * screenHeight * screenWidth;
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                newarrs =new byte[bufferSize];
                log("constructor width:- " + screenWidth + " height:- " + screenHeight);
            }


            public void capture() {
                // Take the Data from frame buffer and store in buffer
                log("capture Screen");

                BufferedInputStream bis = null;

                try {
                // log("in try");
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/data/fb0.raw"));
                readSize = bis.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bis.close();
               } 
               catch (Exception e) {
                // log("in catch");
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
                encodeYUV420(buffer);
                byte[] arr = resize1(buffer);
                FileOutputStream fos;
                try {
                     File f = Files.getImageFile();
                     fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                     fos.write(arr);
                     fos.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
               }
          private byte[] resize1(byte[] buffer) {
              final int RATIO = 4;
              byte[][][] newBuff = new byte[screenWidth][screenHeight][4];
              int pos1 = 0;
              for (int i = 0; i < screenWidth; i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < screenHeight; j++) {
              newBuff[i][j][0] = buffer[pos1++];
              newBuff[i][j][1] = buffer[pos1++];
              newBuff[i][j][2] = buffer[pos1++];
              newBuff[i][j][3] = buffer[pos1++];
         }
        }
              byte[] buffer1 = new byte[buffer.length*3 / (RATIO * RATIO)];
              int pos2 = 0;
              int i = 0, j = 0;
              for (i = 0; i < screenWidth; i++) {
              for (j = 0; j < screenHeight; j++) {
              try {
                   if (i % RATIO == 0 && j % RATIO == 0) {
                   buffer1[pos2++] = newBuff[i][j][0];
                   buffer1[pos2++] = newBuff[i][j][1];
                   buffer1[pos2++] = newBuff[i][j][2];
                   buffer1[pos2++] = newBuff[i][j][3];
              }
             } catch (Exception e) {
            log(" i " + i + " j " + j);
            }
           }
        }

                   log(" valuesof i " + i + " j " + j);
                   if (pos2 == buffer.length / (RATIO * RATIO))
                    log("S size:- " + pos2);
                   else
                    log("F size:- " + pos2);

                    return buffer1;
            }

            private byte[] encodeYUV420(byte[] argb) {

                byte[] yuv420sp = new byte[(screenHeight * screenWidth * 3) / 2];
                final int frameSize = screenWidth * screenHeight;
                int yIndex = 0;
                int uIndex = frameSize;
                int vIndex = frameSize + (frameSize / 4);
                int R, G, B;
                int Y, U, V;
                int index = 0;

                for (int j = 0; j < screenHeight; j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < screenWidth; i++) {
                int pp = (j * screenWidth + i) * 4;
                //a = (argb[index] & 0xff000000) >> 24; // a is not used obviously
                R = (argb[index] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                G = (argb[index] & 0xff00) >> 8;
                B = (argb[index] & 0xff) >> 0;
                Y = ((66 * R + 129 * G + 25 * B + 128) >> 8) + 16;
                U = ((-38 * R - 74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
                V = ((112 * R - 94 * G - 18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128; 
                yuv420sp[yIndex++] = (byte) ((Y < 0) ? 0 : ((Y > 255) ? 255 : Y));
                if (j % 2 == 0 && i % 2 == 0) {
                yuv420sp[uIndex++] = (byte) ((U<0) ? 0 : ((U > 255) ? 255 : U));
                yuv420sp[vIndex++] = (byte) ((V<0) ? 0 : ((V > 255) ? 255 : V)); 

              }
            }
            return yuv420sp;    
        }
```

---

### Update:

Screenshot illustrating the problem:
[image: Example image uploaded on behalf of OP]

I think I have made some changes and it looks some what as the original image but it is not clear or legible.Can I get some ideas on how to make it almost as the original image

```
Image(Context context) {
                // This Constructor is used to initialize height and width of screen
                screenHeight = 800;//m1.heightPixels;
                screenWidth = 480;//m1.widthPixels;
                bufferSize = 4 * screenHeight * screenWidth;
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                newarrs =new byte[bufferSize];
                log("constructor width:- " + screenWidth + " height:- " + screenHeight);
            }


            public void capture() {
                // Take the Data from frame buffer and store in buffer
                log("capture Screen");

                BufferedInputStream bis = null;

                try {
                // log("in try");
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/data/fb0.raw"));
                readSize = bis.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bis.close();
               } 
               catch (Exception e) {
                // log("in catch");
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
                encodeYUV420(buffer);
                byte[] arr = resize1(buffer);
                FileOutputStream fos;
                try {
                     File f = Files.getImageFile();
                     fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                     fos.write(arr);
                     fos.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
               }
          private byte[] resize1(byte[] buffer) {
              final int RATIO = 4;
              byte[][][] newBuff = new byte[screenWidth][screenHeight][4];
              int pos1 = 0;
              for (int i = 0; i < screenWidth; i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < screenHeight; j++) {
              newBuff[i][j][0] = buffer[pos1++];
              newBuff[i][j][1] = buffer[pos1++];
              newBuff[i][j][2] = buffer[pos1++];
              newBuff[i][j][3] = buffer[pos1++];
         }
        }
              byte[] buffer1 = new byte[buffer.length*3 / (RATIO * RATIO)];
              int pos2 = 0;
              int i = 0, j = 0;
              for (i = 0; i < screenWidth; i++) {
              for (j = 0; j < screenHeight; j++) {
              try {
                   if (i % RATIO == 0 && j % RATIO == 0) {
                   buffer1[pos2++] = newBuff[i][j][0];
                   buffer1[pos2++] = newBuff[i][j][1];
                   buffer1[pos2++] = newBuff[i][j][2];
                   buffer1[pos2++] = newBuff[i][j][3];
              }
             } catch (Exception e) {
            log(" i " + i + " j " + j);
            }
           }
        }

                   log(" valuesof i " + i + " j " + j);
                   if (pos2 == buffer.length / (RATIO * RATIO))
                    log("S size:- " + pos2);
                   else
                    log("F size:- " + pos2);

                    return buffer1;
            }

            private byte[] encodeYUV420(byte[] argb) {

                byte[] yuv420sp = new byte[(screenHeight * screenWidth * 3) / 2];
                final int frameSize = screenWidth * screenHeight;
                int yIndex = 0;
                int uvIndex=frameSize;
                int a, R, G, B, Y, U, V;
                int index = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                 for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                  int pp = (j * width + i) * 4;
                    R = argb[pp+ 0];
                    G = argb[pp + 1];
                    B = argb[pp + 2];
                    a = argb[pp + 3];
                    Y = ( (  66 * R + 129 * G +  25 * B + 128) >> 8) +  16;
                    U = ( ( -38 * R -  74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
                    V = ( ( 112 * R -  94 * G -  18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;

 
            yuv420sp[yIndex++] = (byte) ((Y < 0) ? 0 : ((Y > 255) ? 255 : Y));
            if (j % 2 == 0 && i % 2 == 0) { 
                yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte)((U<0) ? 0 : ((U > 255) ? 255 : U));
                yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte)((V<0) ? 0 : ((V > 255) ? 255 : V));
               
              }
            }
            return yuv420sp;    
        }
```

[image: After chnaage image]

Comment: can you indent your code please?

Answer (score 0):

You're not storing the YUV data correctly. According to [this document](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sprab77a/sprab77a.pdf), YUV420SP data is stored in two planes, one containing the Y data, and another containing the interleaved U and V data:

```
|  Y_0  |  Y_1  |  Y_2  |  Y_3  |  Y_4  | ... | Y_w-2 | Y_w-1 |   /* h rows */
|  Y_w  | Y_w+1 | Y_w+2 | ...
    :
    :
|  U_0  |  V_0  |  U_2  |  V_2  |  U_4  | ... | U_w-2 | V_w-2 |   /* h/2 rows */
|  U_2w |  V_2w | U_2w+2| ...
    :
    :
```

Your code seems to be storing the U and V data in separate planes:

```
int uIndex = frameSize;
int vIndex = frameSize + (frameSize / 4);
```

Comment: Is there any native api I can use or what should I use then if my sample code part is wrong?

Comment: Use one pointer to store the U and V values (`uvIndex = frameSize;`), and then store alternating U and V values in this plane (`if (j%2==0) yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (i%2==0) ? U : V;`, where U and V are the values calculated for the same value of `i` (i.e., U_0, V_0, U_2, V_2, etc.). Incidentally, you're discarding three quarters of the U and V values calculated by this code. You can make it run faster by only calculating these values when you actually need them.

Comment: Still it is coming greenish and not even close to any conversion.
Please help in any further way possible.

Comment: Upload some examples of the input and output images. That might help.

Comment: If we want to see the image in yuv format in byte array should it be copied in the same way or reversed?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. You said the resulting images are coming out greenish. Please take a screenshot or do whatever else you have to do to put this into an image file, then post it here next to an image showing what it was supposed to look like.

Comment: I have found the solution for this but it seems none of the people have answered any question and this site has been of very little help to me.:(.

Comment: I suggest you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve